# Почему не передается Context?

Tags: java, android

У меня такая проблема у меня есть класс который работает с `Context`, но сам этот класс не наследует от `Activity` и поэтому я просто решил передавать `Context` в функцию которой он нужен и вот тут проблема я перед тем как положить `Context` в функцию проверяю его и он не `null`, но когда я проверяю его внутри функции которая его приняла, то он уже в ней почему то становиться `null`... И я не могу без него создать `SharedPreferences` Не пойму, что за магия такая... Что я делаю не так

Вот так я передаю его и он не null

```
UserAccess.saveAccess(getApplicationContext(), cursor);
```

и вот функция которая принимает его и в ней он уже null

```
public static void saveAccess(Context context, Cursor cursor){ 
SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences("Compare",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

И естественно когда я делаю `getSharedPreferences()` то там тоже `null`
Как такое может быть?

Comment: передаете context1, а используете context откуда-то взявшийся)

Comment: извиняюсь за ошибку, это я нечайно поставил 1... сейчас поправил вопрос. В настоящем коде этой ошибки нет и выглядит от так как сейчас после того как я его исправил...

Comment: getApplicationContext() точно у вас не null?

Comment: попробуйте вместо `getApplicationContext()` сделать `MyActivity.this`. Или откуда вы его берете?

Comment: Странно, пошел чай попил, вернулся и все заработало)) Серьезно... даже не знаю как так получилось...

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void saveAccess(Context **context1**, Cursor cursor){ 
     SharedPreferences sPref = **context**.getSharedPreferences("Compare",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Разные переменные. В сигнатуре объявлена переменная context1, а использовать пытаетесь context.

Comment: извиняюсь за ошибку, это я нечайно поставил 1... сейчас поправил вопрос. В настоящем коде этой ошибки нет и выглядит от так как сейчас после того как я его исправил...

Comment: Как вы узнали, что он null? Было выброшено исключение NullPointerException? Если вам `getSharedPreferences()` возвращает null, это значит, что context как раз не null.

Comment: Странно, пошел чай попил, вернулся и все заработало)) Серьезно... даже не знаю как так получилось...

Comment: Но все же `getSharedPreferences()` до сих пор почему то не создает таблицу... Или создает, но я не могу понять где